# Monotouch launches wrong debugger hardware

Tags: iphone, debugging, ios-simulator, xamarin.ios

I'm debugging a Monotouch app (created with mostly the default settings). When I ask it to debug in the simulator, it launches with the wrong hardware type -- iPad even though I'm developing for iPhone.

How do I switch this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from

http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst1185.aspx

someone answered:

```
In your project's options in MonoDevelop, go to "iPhone Build" and change your SDK version to something higher than 3.2. 3.2 is the version of iPad's SDK.
```

I think the detail is that the 3.2 SDK was never an iPhone SDK, it was an iPad SDK. Now things are unified with iOS as of 4.2.

Comment: I had done this actually, but I didn't notice you have to set the SDK version separately for both simulator and physical device.